# How do I Change font color in a text box if number is above a certain value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I would like to change the color of my text in my text box to blue if the number is above 5.

What is the simplest way to do this?

I thought there would be a simple `textbox.FontColor = Blue;` but I cant find anything like this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need a data trigger and a value converter --

```
<DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Path=PROPERTY,
                Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanConverter},
                ConverterParameter=5}"
                Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextBox.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
```

Converter might look like --

```
 public class GreaterThanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var limit = (int)parameter;
        return (int)value > limit;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the full right approach. Setting `Foreground` in code-behind is usually not correct.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, by code-behind do you mean the xaml written in the first paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

```
textbox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

Comment: thank you, I've read a whole c sharp book and I still get stumped with stuff like this, is there an easy way to look it up?

Comment: You are welcome.. Well, when I don't know what property for a given element should I use, I try looking it up at its class reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx or maybe here at SO.. Or even using intellisense, trying to guess the property name . Anyway, you are going to get more fluent with these controls' properties as your experience increases..

Comment: don't wish to negate this one, but you will eventually learn all the property names but try to learn the right way to set those, trust me cutting corners in initial stages will cost you lot going forward.